# What is the difference between m/s and m/s/s?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Can I subtract, say, for example, 600 m/s - 20 m/s/s? I am confused about this topic and there is no good information on the web.

Answer (score 5):

To demonstrate why you can't do this, let's step up one derivative, and explore an anecdote about why it doesn't much sense to add distance and velocity directly.

---

I ask you, "How far away is your house from Jill's house?"

You answer, "It is is five kilometers plus seventeen meters per second away." ($5 \,\text{km} + 17\,\text{m/s}$.)

**I was asking you for a distance.** But you gave me something that was neither a distance, nor a velocity, but some garbled summation of units.

Confused by your answer, I decide to change the subject. "How fast do you think that car is driving over there?"

You answer, "It is driving ten miles per hour, minus fourteen feet." ($10 \,\text{mph} - 14\,\text{ft}$.)

*Wait, what are you talking about?* I wonder.

**I was asking you for a speed.** But you gave me something that was neither a speed, nor a distance, but some garbled summation of units.

If I ask for distance, give me a distance. If I ask for a velocity, give me a velocity.

The same principle applies for all units, and is precisely why checking your units at the end of a derivation is a great sanity check that at least you are attempting to express the type of quantity you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.m/s tells us how fast something is moving/ rate of change of distance and m/s/s tells us the rate of change of speed. we cant subtract them because these two are very different from each other.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sensical way to add or subtract them together since they are terms that have completely different units and mean totally different things.

Velocity is the *rate of change of displacement* whilst acceleration is the rate of change of velocity or in other words the rate of change of *the rate of change of displacement.* If we think of something that is a rate of change as providing units of $s^{-1}$
then the rate of change of displacement will have units of $ms^{-1}$ and the rate of change of this velocity will have units of $ms^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In physics, we can add or subtract only those terms which have same dimensions (or SI units).

Velocity $(ms^{-1})$ and acceleration $(ms^{-2})$ are terms having different dimensions each so we can't add or subtract them from each other.